# Add display property to accordion onload depending on resolution

Tags: javascript, accordion, onload, display

I'm using the W3C accordion on my website, and only want the accordion to be active when the page is under 768px. So far, I have the script adjusted so that the "panel" div's will toggle, but they initially are displayed, rather than hidden. Is there a line I can add to the code to initially hide the panel div's when the resolution is under 768px? I've tried adding display:none to the element in the css sheet, but the toggle script won't override it.

Hope this makes sense!

```
<script>
if (screen.width < 768) {
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("filterAccordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: "the W3C accordion" — There's no such thing. Are you confusing W3C (standards organisation) with W3Schools (purveyor of out of date, error-prone, and advertising riddled tutorials and references)?

Comment: @Quentin I suspect OP is referring to : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp . OP are you looking to hide the accordion on resize ? Have you looked into CSS mediaQueries ? IE : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution. Please note that I have commented out some code to demonstrate it in desktop view. Please uncomment that and your code should work in "mobile only" scenario.

```js
document.querySelector('.accordion').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  /*if (screen.width < 768) {*/
  var currentTarget = e.target;
  if (e.target.classList.contains('accordion-title')) {
    var allDesc = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-description'));
    allDesc.forEach(function (el) {
      el.classList.add('hidden-xs');
    });
    e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('hidden-xs');
  }
  /*}*/
});
```

```css
/*@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none;
  }
}*/

/* Comment below code and uncomment above */

/* For demo purpose only */
.hidden-xs {
  display: none;
}

.accordion-title,
.accordion-description {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.accordion-title {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-title">Title 1</div>
  <div class="accordion-description hidden-xs">Some description</div>
   <div class="accordion-title">Title 2</div>
  <div class="accordion-description hidden-xs">Some description</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you can manage this in CSS..

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .filterAccordion {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

As for the accordian and mentioned by Quentin.. W3Schools is probably not the best source of information.. For general modules like this perhaps Bootstrap(3/4) might be a more ideal framework if you are open to use one at all.

Edit : [MediaQueries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)